# System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper' does not contain a definition for CheckBox

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Text;
namespace secondMvc.MyControls
{
    public static class CheckBoxList
    {
        public static MvcHtmlString CheckListBox(this HtmlHelper helper, string Name, Dictionary<Int32, string> citiesList, bool IsVertical, string cssClass)
        {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

            sb.Append(string.Format("<div >"));
            foreach (var item in citiesList)
            {


                sb.Append(helper.CheckBox(item.Value, true, new { @class = cssClass, value = item.Key }));
                sb.Append(helper.Label("RadioButtonItems", item.Value));
                sb.Append("&nbsp;");
                if (IsVertical) sb.Append("<br>");

            }
            sb.Append("</div> ");
            return MvcHtmlString.Create(sb.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

`System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper`'`does not contain a definition for`CheckBox`and no extension method`'CheckBox'`accepting a first argument of type`'System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper'` could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

i change web.config like this:

```
<configuration>

    <appSettings>

    </appSettings>

    <connectionStrings>

    </connectionStrings>
  <pages>
    <namespaces>

      <add namespace="secondMvc.MyControls"/>
    </namespaces>
  </pages>

  <system.web>
    <compilation>
      <assemblies>
      <add assembly="secondMvc.MyControls" />
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

but i have same error.
any idea?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Add `using System.Web.Mvc.Html` to your file containing the `CheckBoxList` static class. It is inside this namespace that extension method such as `CheckBox` are defined. The `web.config` namespaces section is completely ignored when compiling C# code. They are used by views. And note that Razor views use the `~/Views/web.config` file, not `~/web.config`, so make sure you have added the `secondMvc.MyControls` namespace to the correct web.config if you want your custom extension method to be resolved in views.

Comment: what do you mean make sure you have added the secondMvc.MyControls namespace? i have added System.Web.Mvc.Html to my main web config and views web.config and still get this error?